# LaTeXでjunsrt.bstファイルが開けない

Tags: vscode, latex

VSCode上でLaTeXを使っているのですが、参考文献を書く際`\bibliographystyle{junsrt}`を読み込もうとすると

```
I couldn't open style file junsrt.bst
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。unsrt.bstだとうまくいきました。junsrt.bstが他のunsrt.bstなどがあるフォルダ（C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\bibtex\bst\base）になかったので[こちらのgithub](https://github.com/texjporg/pbibtex-base/blob/master/junsrt.bst)からjunsrt.bstをインストールして入れました。しかしコンパイルしても再び同じエラーが出てしまいました。どのようにすればよいでしょうか。以下が簡略化したコードです。

```
%ctrl+Alt+BでPDFビルド
%ctrl+Alt+Vで右にPDF表示
%ctrl+alt+jでPDFへジャンプ
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{ltjsarticle} %reportはarticleと違いchapterを含む
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{ascmac}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{here} %画像の表示位置調整用
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{url} % url{}でurlをハイパーリンクでつけれる
\usepackage{physics2}
\usephysicsmodule{ab.braket}
\usephysicsmodule{ab} % automatic braces, 自動括弧
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{enumitem} %箇条書きのバリエーション広がる
\usepackage{siunitx} %SI単位系

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % 目次表示の深さレベル
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %見出し番号の深さレベル
\graphicspath{{latex/}{paper_figs/}} % 違うファイル内の画像も使いたい
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 % 脚注の位置調整
%======================================================================
\title{タイトル}
\author{著者}
\date{\today}
%======================================================================
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
%==================================================================
\section{はじめ}
\cite{key}
\bibliographystyle{junsrt}
\bibliography{test} % 参考文献を入れる.bib fileの名前
%======================================================================
\end{document}
```

またtest.bibファイルはこちらです。

```
@misc{key,
  author       = {著者},
  howpublished = {},
  title        = {タイトル},
  year         = {}
}
```

Comment: ご質問の件はインストールの問題だと思われます。「unsrt.bstをインストールして入れました」とありますが、具体的にどのような手順でインストールされたのでしょうか？ 話の流れからすると、インストールしたのはjunsrt.bstなのかなと思いますが、質問文では**unsrt.bst**をインストールしたとおっしゃっていますし、リンク先は**jplain.bst**のようです。正確には、どのファイルをインストールされたのでしょうか？

正しくインストールできている場合は、コマンドラインで`kpsewhich junsrt.bst`を実行するとインストール先のパスが表示されます。現状では、おそらく`kpsewhich unsrt.bst`は何らかのパスを返す一方、`kpsewhich junsrt.bst`ではなにも出力されないのではないでしょうか。ご確認ください。

Comment: 失礼しました。インストールしたのは修正したリンク先のjunsrt.bstです。github上のjunsrt.bstのコード右上にある"download raw file"からファイルをダウンロードしてそのままunsrt.bstと同じフォルダに入れました。

Comment: おっしゃる通りcmd でkpwewhich junsrt.bstを実行しても何も出力されませんでした。

Comment: junsrtが使えている友人のパソコンでもjunsrt.bstファイルが見つからなかったので、別のファイルを開いているのかもしれません。

Comment: ご質問の件はインストールの問題だと思われるので、記載いただいたLaTeXソースは問題には直接は関係がなさそうです。なのでこのコメントは蛇足ですが、`\usepackage{url} % url{}でurlをハイパーリンクでつけれる`というのは事実誤認です。`\url`をハイパーリンク化するのはurlパッケージではなくhyperrefパッケージの機能です。urlパッケージの`\url`はリンクを（いい感じに）印刷するコマンドです。hyperrefパッケージが内部でurlパッケージを読み込むため、このパッケージを読み込んでいる場合は、別にurlパッケージを読み込む必要はありません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

junsrt.bstが正しくインストールできていないのが原因だと思われます。以下ではjunsrt.bstを正しくインストールする方法を説明します。方法はいくつかありますが、正しい方法と（動作するものの）間違った方法があります。

**注意：質問者は`C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\bibtex\bst\base`にjunsrt.bstを配置されたようですが、これは誤った方法です。** 詳細は最後の「間違った方法」のところで解説します。

#### 正しい方法① 最も簡単だが、一時的なインストール

LaTeXでタイプセットしたいソースファイル（`*.tex`）と同じ場所にjunsrt.bstを配置してください。これで、とりあえずその文書についてはjunsrt.bstによる文献リストの作成が可能になるはずです。

この方法は簡単ですが、他の文書でもjunsrtを用いてタイプセットしたい場合には、毎回junsrt.bstをその文書と同じディレクトリにコピーする必要があります。

#### 正しい方法② 恒久的なインストール

junsrt.bstをシステムにインストールし、今回限りでなく今後も利用できるようにする方法です。まず、`kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME`を実行してTEXMFHOMEの位置を調べます。Windowsの場合はおそらく`C:\user\<ユーザ名>\texmf`と表示されるはずです。以降、このTEXMFHOMEのパス位置を`$TEXMFHOME`と表記します。

その上で、junsrt.bibは`$TEXMFHOME\bibtex\bst\base`に配置してください。これで、どのディレクトリのどの文書でもjunsrt.bstを用いたタイプセットが可能になるはずです。インストールを行ったら、`kpsewhich junsrt.bib`を実行してパス位置`$TEXMFHOME\bibtex\bst\base`が表示されることを確認してみてください。

#### 間違った方法

TeX関連のファイルの恒久的なインストールはTEXMFHOME（またはTEXMFLOCAL。後述）以下に行うのが正解です。一方、質問者がインストールを試みた場所（`C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\bibtex\bst\base`）はTEXMFDIST以下のパス位置です。**TEXMFDISTにはユーザ自身がファイルをインストールしてはいけません。**

TEXMFDISTはTeX Liveの配布者（英語ではdistributorと言います）が配布しているいわば「公式の」ファイルを配置する場所です。TEXMFDIST内のファイルの管理者はTeX Live配布者です。そのため、TEXMFDIST内にファイルを配置すると、TeX Liveをアップデートした際などにファイルが消去されてしまったり、上書きされてしまう可能性があります。これは予期せぬトラブルに繋がる虞があります。

このように、TEXMFDISTに対する直接のファイルインストールは避けるべきですが、きちんと操作を行うとTEXMFDISTにもファイルをインストールを行うことは可能です（やらないでください）。TEXMFDISTやTEXMFLOCALなどのパス位置では、ほとんどの場合TeXによるファイル捜索を効率化するためls-Rというしくみが採用されています。ls-Rが有効になっている場合、ファイルをパス位置に配置するだけではインストールが完了せず、その後にコマンドラインで`mktexlsr`を実行する必要があります。

#### おまけ：用語の解説

TEXMFDIST、TEXMFHOME、TEXMFLOCALなど、質問者にとっては色々と聞き慣れないと思われる用語を出してしまったので、最後にこれらについてまとめておきます。こうしたTEXMFﾅﾝﾁｬﾗというのはTeX関連のファイルを配置するパス位置のことで、TEXMFツリーと呼ばれます。

- TEXMFDIST: TeX Live配布者（distributor）が配布しているファイルを配置する場所。基本的に一般ユーザは変更を加えてはいけません
- TEXMFHOME: TeX Liveを利用する個人のユーザがファイルを配置してよい場所。ほとんどのケースでは、変更が必要な場合はこのツリーを利用しましょう
- TEXMFLOCAL: TeX Liveを利用するシステム（PC）の管理者がファイルを配置してよい場所。このツリーに対する変更は、同じシステムを利用する全ユーザに影響します。ファイルをインストールする場合には`mktexlsr`の実行が必要です

Comment: ' C:\user\<ユーザ名>\texmf ' は表示されたのですが、実際の場所にフォルダが見つかりませんでした。自分で'$TEXMFHOME\bibtex\bst\base'とフォルダを作っていって'junsrt.bst'を置いたのですが、コンパイルしても同じようにエラーがでてしまいました。

Comment: 一応確認ですが`$TEXMFHOME\bibtex\bst\base`を作ったというのは`C:\user\<ユーザ名>\texmf\bibtex\bst\base`というフォルダを作ったという意味で合っていますか？（`$TEXMFHOME`という文字列をそのままパス名にしていないかの確認です） それで動かないとしたら別の問題がありそうです。実際の場所にフォルダがない場合は作るという対応で正しいです。

Comment: そのような意味であってます。ただtexlive2023フォルダ内にtexmf-configとtexmf-varという名前のフォルダがあったので、それに合わせてフォルダ名をtexmf-homeと書いていました。

Comment: texmf-homeと書いていたのをtexmfに直したら読み込めたようです。しかし先ほどまでのエラーは消えたのですが今度は別のエラーが出てきました。”Recipe terminated with error”と表示されて赤色の×が出てきたのですがProblemに何も表示されていません。質問した内容とはまた別の問題のようなのですが、この場合新しく質問を作り直したほうがよいのでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね、junsrt.bstファイルが見つからないという問題は解決したのであれば、別の問題は質問をわけた方がわかりやすそうです（私の回答が解決の役に立った場合は[回答の承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をしてもらえると大変嬉しいです）。新規に質問する場合、さすがに「エラーになります」だけだと有益な回答を付けるのが難しいので、もう少し情報があるとよいと思います。関係のない\usepackage等は削って、問題のエラーが発生するなるべく小さいソースコード（Minimal Working Example; MWE）を作ってもらえると、解決の可能性が高まると思います。